# How to take a slice of an array / dictionary and append

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, append, slice

I have an array / dictionary of testWords that is pulled from a plist. I want to randomly shuffle them, take a slice of 2 and append that to another words array. For some reason I can't append the testWords to the words array. I also need a version of the random shuffle, select, append for iOS8.

```
var words: [NSArray]

var testWords: [NSArray]!

let fileName = "level\(levelNumber).plist"
let levelPath = "\(NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!)/\(fileName)"
let levelDictionary: NSDictionary? = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: levelPath)
testWords = levelDictionary!["words"] as! [NSArray]

let shuffledTestWords = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(testWords)
         print("testWords after shuffling is \(shuffledTestWords)")

let chosenWords = Array(shuffledTestWords.prefix(2))
words.appendContentsOf(Array(chosenWords))
```

The array looks like this in the console:

```
testWords after shuffling is [(
"drinc drink",
drink,
"Which one is right?",
"",
""
), (
"bank banc",
bank,
"Spell this word ending in  ' nk '",
"",
""
), (
"bunk bunc",
bunk,
"Spell this word ending in  ' nk '",
"",
""
)]
```

Any ideas on how to append such an array much appreciated! Now answered.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly prefix will return an ArraySlice, which is not an array.
Secondly the `append` method add one new element to the array.

So in your case you could do: `words.appendContentsOf(Array(chosenWords))`.
[appendContentsOf](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/type/Array/#func-appendContentsOf)
and `Array()` will create an array from your `ArraySlice`.

Comment: Thanks Zico. I also added let chosenWords = Array(shuffledTestWords.prefix(2))